# Continuous boost::asio reads

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I'm experimenting with Boost::asio, and I'm trying to make a client that reads and outputs to console packets sent from a server. The server uses a proprietary protolcol. It sends a timer update every second, responds to ping, and can reply with a list of files when the client asks for it. I have a decent grasp of asynchronous networking, but I'm having a 
problem. Here's the code:

```
class JReader
{
public:
  JReader(boost::asio::io_service &io_s)
    : socket_(io_s)
  {
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_s);
    tcp::resolver::query query("xxxx", "yyyy");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;

    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
    {
      socket_.close();
      socket_.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
    }
    if (error)
    {     
      throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    }


    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(connect, 12), boost::bind(&JReader::handle_write, this));
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(getlist, 3), boost::bind(&JReader::handle_write, this));

    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buf_, BUF_SIZE), boost::bind(&JReader::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
private:

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code err, size_t bytes)
  {        
    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::string(buf_, bytes);
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buf_, BUF_SIZE), boost::bind(&JReader::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_write()
  {
    //TODO: finish this!
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"Wrote something";

  }

  static const int BUF_SIZE = 256;
  char buf_[BUF_SIZE];
  tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

The program reads from the server and outputs data to console -- but the motherboard makes a terrible beeping sound. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my handle_read loop.

What is the correct, nonblocking way of continually listening to a server?

Answer (score 4):

Ah ha! My use of asio was correct, but my mistake was streaming binary data to std::cout!! I used a filestream instead, and now it works. :)

Comment: streaming binary to std::cout always makes noise :-)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using `async_write` correctly, posting two asynchronous writes concurrently is an application error.  This is described in [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) for `async_write`

> This operation is implemented in terms
>   of zero or more calls to the stream's
>   async_write_some function, and is
>   known as a composed operation. **The
>   program must ensure that the stream
>   performs no other write operations**
>   (such as async_write, the stream's
>   async_write_some function, or any
>   other composed operations that perform
>   writes) until this operation
>   completes.

You most likely are observing correct behavior because the data you are sending is so short (12 and 3 bytes, respectively).  I suggest posting the second `async_write` after the handler for your first one is invoked.