# Boost Asio async_send produces beep sound

Tags: c++, audio, boost-asio, beep

Trying to write a client for a type of server which behaves like an echo server. When I try to send something, it produces a beep sound. I've found that the problem arise at line 356 (on my editor) of win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp file. The code is:

```
int result = ::WSASend(impl.socket_, buffers,
        static_cast<DWORD>(buffer_count), &bytes_transferred, flags, op, 0);
```

Then I made some research.

[Continuous boost::asio reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048288/continuous-boostasio-reads) here in the comment of the answer, someone said when a binary data is being written to `std::cout`.

[Why does the following code make my computer beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207034/why-does-the-following-code-make-my-computer-beep?rq=1) here, it seems like the problem is same. They concluded that a '\a' is what produced the sound.

Debugging the application, the buffer of the API function I mentioned earlier, contains the following:

```
"asd@ıııı2•Z\x1aP"
```

here "asd@" is my string, the rest changes every time when I debug and I don't know what are they. Now, this is probably the part which the sound is produced, but my question how do I prevent it?

I have the following implementation of a one-round "Correspond" function. Note that I also have a isolated `Send()` function implementation, which can be paired with `ReadUntil()` explicitly to achieve same result. Using `Send()` and `ReadUntil()` together, the beep sound is still produced. Normally, this shouldn't happen as I am *not* dealing with low-level API functions, but Boost.Asio. Am I doing something wrong?

**CODES**

```
void Correspond(const std::string &data,
                const std::string &delim,
                std::vector<char> &response)
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> localbuffer = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(data.begin(), data.end());

    // pass shared_ptr to callback function to prolong the buffer's lifetime
    // !!! perhaps a better buffer management is needed
    socket.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(*localbuffer),
                      std::bind(&TCPClient::on_correspond,
                                this,
                                std::placeholders::_1,
                                std::placeholders::_2,
                                delim,
                                std::ref(response),
                                localbuffer));
}
```

and following callback implementation

```
void on_correspond(const boost::system::error_code& errorcode,
                   std::size_t sent,
                   const std::string &delim,
                   std::vector<char> &response,
                   const std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> &buffer)
{
    if(errorcode) {
        SLOGERROR(mutex, errorcode.message(), "on_correspond()");
    }

    if(sent == 0) {
        SLOG(mutex, "0 bytes sent w/o errors", "on_correspond()");
    }

    ReadUntil(delim, response);
}
```

After debugging deep into API, I've found this issue is not related with read function, but I will post it here just to be sure.

```
void ReadUntil(const std::string &delim, std::vector<char> &response)
{
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket,
                                  buffer,
                                  delim,
                                  std::bind(&TCPClient::on_readuntil,
                                            this,
                                            std::placeholders::_1,
                                            std::placeholders::_2,
                                            std::ref(response)));
}
void on_readuntil(const boost::system::error_code& errorcode,
                  std::size_t received,
                  std::vector<char> &response)
{
    SLOG(mutex, "on_readuntil invoked", "on_readuntil()");
    SLOG(mutex, received, "on_readuntil");
    // !!! needs error handling, short-read handling and whatnot
    if(errorcode) {
        SLOGERROR(mutex, errorcode.message(), "on_readuntil()");
        return;
    }

    if(received == 0) {
        SLOG(mutex, "0 bytes received w/o errors", "on_readuntil()");
    }

    response.reserve(received);
    std::copy(boost::asio::buffers_begin(buffer.data()),
              boost::asio::buffers_begin(buffer.data()) + received,
              std::back_inserter(response));
    buffer.consume(received);
}
```

Comment: `here "asd@" is my string, the rest changes every time when I debug` looks like the buffer is read without caring about the size of it, welcome to C++. Might wanna give the boost::asio::buffer a hint about the buffers size.

Comment: Do you mean I should prepare() the buffer? I was planning to manually manage all commits and consumes but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478278/working-with-boostasiostreambuf/28504203?noredirect=1#comment64612843_28504203), someone told me that it is automatically managed if `boost::asio::streambuf` itself is used in asio functions.

Comment: Have you tried disabling console output and testing to see if you're still getting the beeps?

Comment: @Xirema, Disabling all sorts of console logs/outputs didn't help

Comment: @Backtempel, I think I misunderstood what you are trying to say. I thought you are talking about read functions when in fact problem was (probably) about send function. After giving data's size to boost::asio::buffer used in `Send()` and `Correspond()` functions, it stopped beeping (finally). If you write an answer, I shall accept it. I can't believe I missed it :>

Comment: @Blacktempel The [`boost::asio::buffer(vector)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload23.html) overload being used deduces the size of the buffer.  In this case, explicitly providing a size should not be required if one wishes to send the entire buffer.  @Cengiz I rarely find a need to explicitly provide size to `boost::asio::buffer()`.  If explicitly providing `data.size()` as the size to `boost::asio::buffer()` changes the behavior of the program, then I would be suspicious and investigate further.

Comment: @Tanner, do you think the problem is on my end? I merely use these async functions. Giving size indeed silenced the beep. Thank you for the tip, I will investigate further.

Comment: Given `buffer(*localbuffer)` is the equivalent of `buffer(*localbuffer, localbuffer->size())` and `buffer(*localbuffer, data.size())` ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/244301a19d945493)), I would be surprised if that is the fundamental source of the problem. If I was getting a system beep, I would suspect that the ASCII Bell character (0x07) is getting written to the console.  In particular, the unicode bullet • (0x2022) that appears in the buffer can be converted into the ASCII Bell character (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070104-12/?p=28513)).

Comment: @Tanner, can you read my comment under the answer? It seems like some string contained within the shared_ptr is passed to the WDASend(), which then tries to send it. [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619486/boost-asio-async-send-produces-beep-sound/38626844?noredirect=1#comment64666673_38626844)

Comment: @Cengiz I have read the comments and would expect the string contained within the buffer to be passed to `WDASend()`.  I still postulate that the ASCII Bell character is being written to a console.

Comment: @Tanner, I think you are right. It might have been a problem with server writing some problematic character to the console. It could be the case that I've been looking at the wrong side. I made a mistake by chance, and had to recompiled the async echo server example from boost website. This time, I used proper console outputs on the server side, rather than quick jobs. It silenced the problem. If I can isolate it even further, I will write it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`here "asd@" is my string, the rest changes every time when I debug`

The buffer is read without caring about the size of it, welcome to C++. Give the `boost::asio::buffer` the buffers size.

Comment: the problem occurred again, unfortunately. After debugging even more, I realized the contents of shared_ptr and the message I am trying to send are the same. Like following `[Raw View] {_Myval2={_Myfirst=0x004828a8 "asd@ııııú¥¿\x2" _Mylast=0x004828ac "ııııú¥¿\x2" _Myend=0x004828ac "ııııú¥¿\x2" } } std::_Compressed_pair<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char> >,std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<char> >,1>`. Notice _asd@ııııú¥¿\x2_, this is the exact string that `WSASend()` is trying to send and causing beeps. What do you think the problem is here?

Comment: @CengizKandemir Could you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem ? I'm on phone, I'll take another look at the question later.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem properly. The MCVE I tried is not beeping. I also recompiled the echo server example I am using, maybe it was actually the server that was beeping due to some problematic cout on the server side. If I isolate the problem even further, I will write here.